# How to get download image url from firebase storage state_changed event?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-storage

This code should work but no matter what i do, I cant seem to get the downloadURL.
I am using vue js. This is the code for file upload.

And below you can see the image that shows the console log. It saved the image successfully, only problem is I dont get downloadURL, there does not seem to be one.

```
// upload file
    uploadFile(file, metadata) {
            if(file === null) return false

            let pathToUpload = this.currentChannel.id
            // parent means Messages.vue getMessagesRef() that returns either public or private channel
            let ref = this.$parent.getMessagesRef()
            // getPath() refers to the path below
            let filePath = this.getPath() + '/' + uuidV4() + '.jpg'

            // upload file
            this.uploadTask = this.storageRef.child(filePath).put(file, metadata)
            // upload state
            this.uploadState = "uploading"


            // on upload state change
            this.uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
                console.log('image uploaded/state_changed in storage: ', snapshot)
                // Upload en cours
                let percent = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                // $("#uploadedFile").progress("set percent", percent)
                $(".progress-bar").css("width", percent+'%')
            }, error => {
                // Error
                this.errors.push(error.message)
                this.uploadState = 'error'
                this.uploadTask = null
            }, () => {
                // Upload finished
                this.uploadState = 'done'
                console.log('done upload')
                // reset form
                this.$refs.file_modal.resetForm()
                // recover the url of file
                let fileUrl = this.uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
                console.log('downloadURL(snapshot) from firebase: ', this.uploadTask.snapshot)

                // sendFileMessage() will pass file as parameter on upload
                this.sendFileMessage(fileUrl, ref, pathToUpload)
            })
    },
```

Console.log() result:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#sube_archivos), you have to call `uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL` in completed callback

```
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
  console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
});
```